# Getting Sinatra running on Ubuntu, Uninitialized constant error

Tags: ubuntu, rubygems, sinatra

Trying to get Sinatra setup on Ubuntu 12.04. I have RVM installed, and I think I have installed all dependencies (listed below). I found another SO post ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11743448/trouble-installing-ruby-on-rails)) that indicated I don't have libssl-dev installed, but it looks like I do. When I run:

```
sudo gem install sinatra
```

I get:

```
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (NameError)
    uninitialized constant Gem::RemoteFetcher::OpenSSL
```

rvm req installs:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential openssl libreadline6 libreadline6-dev curl git-core zlib1g zlib1g-dev libssl-dev libyaml-dev libsq
lite3-dev sqlite3 libxml2-dev libxslt-dev autoconf libc6-dev ncurses-dev automake libtool bison subversion pkg-config

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'libxslt1-dev' instead of 'libxslt-dev'
Note, selecting 'libncurses5-dev' instead of 'ncurses-dev'
autoconf is already the newest version.
automake is already the newest version.
bison is already the newest version.
curl is already the newest version.
git-core is already the newest version.
libncurses5-dev is already the newest version.
libreadline6 is already the newest version.
libtool is already the newest version.
libyaml-dev is already the newest version.
subversion is already the newest version.
zlib1g is already the newest version.
zlib1g-dev is already the newest version.
build-essential is already the newest version.
libc6-dev is already the newest version.
libsqlite3-dev is already the newest version.
libssl-dev is already the newest version.
libxml2-dev is already the newest version.
libxslt1-dev is already the newest version.
openssl is already the newest version.
sqlite3 is already the newest version.
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  libreadline-gplv2-dev
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libreadline6-dev pkg-config
0 upgraded, 2 newly installed, 1 to remove and 7 not upgraded.
Need to get 40.9 kB/305 kB of archives.
After this operation, 201 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y
```

Ruby Version:

```
ruby -v
ruby 1.9.3p327 (2012-11-10 revision 37606) [x86_64-linux]
```

Comment: When you use rvm, you don't need to use `sudo`. Did you try installing the gem without?

Answer (score 1):

Did you install RVM with OpenSSL option? Something like

```
rvm reinstall 1.9.2 --with-openssl-dir=/usr/local
```

Sometimes  you stumble across issues if you have installed Ruby, IRB or RubyGems in System already (for example using apt-get) without RVM.

If not you may want to consider re-installing RVM with OpenSSL. Refer to [RVM Documentation](https://rvm.io/packages/openssl/)

I would also advice to install following packages before installing RVM

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential openssl libreadline6 libreadline6-dev \
curl git-core zlib1g zlib1g-dev libssl-dev libyaml-dev libsqlite3-dev sqlite3 \
libxml2-dev libxslt-dev autoconf libc6-dev ncurses-dev automake libtool bison  \
subversion pkgconfig
```

Comment: Thank you for the tip. Unfortunately, I still get an error: Error running '/home/tpowell/.rvm/scripts/fetch http://ftp.ruby-lang.org/pub/ruby/1.9/
ruby-1.9.2-p320.tar.bz2', please read /home/tpowell/.rvm/log/ruby-1.9.2-p320/fetch.log
There has been an error fetching the ruby interpreter. Halting the installation. Does this work for you? Maybe I have some other firewall problem.

Comment: Did you try to ftp to ftp.ruby-lang.org/pub/ruby/1.9 and see if its getting downloaded? In case its not, it could be network/FTP issue.

Answer (score 1):

This error (uninitialized constant Gem::RemoteFetcher::OpenSSL)
can occur if rubygems.org cannot be resolved via DNS.
It just happened to me.  Once DNS came back to its senses, gem install started
working again.

Comment: Yep, experiencing this right now. 

rubygem.org's status can be checked on twitter (e. g. https://twitter.com/rubygems_status/status/539500893108854785).